# Labels and buttons do not work with tabs in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, tabs, firemonkey

I want to use tabs in a FMX form. In VCL all is functioning as expected. In FMX I tried tabs with labels and buttons without success. `HitTest` is true, no other controls are on the form. The surrounding frame does not appear and pressing the TAB key does nothing. With edit fields it is working. Did I miss something? Current system is Windows 11 Pro 21H2 and Delphi 10.4.2.

Comment: As a `TLabel` is not an input component, you can not `Tab` to it. Tabbing from/to buttons  or edits works very well. If you want to show exactly what you are having problems with, please provide a complete, but [mre].

Comment: ´unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    CornerButton1: TCornerButton;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end. ´

Comment: TButton works well. TCornerButton not. Why do TButton and TLabel have HitTest and TabOrder if that is not supported?

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and put it there, where it belongs. It's part of the question that  you didn't provide to begin with, so add it to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

To tab to a `TLabel`, set its `CanFocus` property to `True`.  As this property is public, not published, you'll need to do that in code, such as in the form's `OnCreate` event or by overriding the form's `Loaded` method.